# Is there an unified pipeline to convert a 4D nifti noisy pet scan image to an averaged, denoised, 3D Nifti image?

Tags: image-preprocessing, noise

What I'm looking is to do at least the step 2 of ADNI pre processing (coregistered, averaged): https://adni.loni.usc.edu/methods/pet-analysis-method/pet-analysis/

OASIS-3 dataset provides FDG PET images but they are noise and in 4D, so I suspect they are "raw" images without pre processing.

Is there an unified PET processing pipeline to do this pre processing?

At least coregister, average, and best scenario all the ADNI pre processing steps.

Comment: From page 22 of https://www.oasis-brains.org/files/OASIS-3_Imaging_Data_Dictionary_v2.3.pdf it looks like that processing may have been done and the results available. It also links to this code for processing: https://github.com/ysu001/PUP is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I saw the same but I think it means that it extracted some data (e.g. numeric data about brain regions) from the images, the site doesn't seem to have processed images. I saw that repository but there is no a lot of documentation, I'll take a look at the scripts anyway. Thanks!